# Using two cursors in PL/SQL

Tags: plsql

```
DECLARE
     AA NUMBER;
     CURSOR S IS SELECT ENAME, SAL
     FROM EMP;
     CURSOR D IS SELECT ENAME, SAL
     FROM EMP;
     NAME EMP.ENAME%TYPE;
     SALARY EMP.SAL%TYPE;
     C NUMBER;
BEGIN
   AA := :NUMBER_OF_EMP;
   SELECT COUNT(EMPNO) INTO C FROM EMP;
    OPEN S;
     FOR A IN 1..AA LOOP
        FETCH S INTO NAME, SALARY;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NAME : '||NAME||'   SALARY :'||SALARY); 
     END LOOP;
CLOSE S;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('  ');
    OPEN D;
      FOR A IN 1..AA LOOP
        FETCH S INTO NAME, SALARY;
         UPDATE EMP
         SET SAL = SAL + 500;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NAME : '||NAME||'   SALARY :'||SALARY); 
     END LOOP;
    CLOSE D;
END;
```

i'm little confusing with cursor. in my code i wana display a name and salary of employees. For example, if the user put 3 in the first cursor will display just 3 employees with ( name and salary). the second cursor will do the same thing but it will change the salary for the same 3 employees and display it again.

```
ORA-01001: invalid cursor
```

Answer (score 0):

The immediately cause of your error is the second FETCH statement. It fetches from cursor S but you closed that cursor above. Changing that to fetch from cursor D will correct the error condition.

But, your procedure has other problems.

1. The "select count(empno)..." is superfluous as you do nothing with the result.
2. The cursors S and D are the same and not open at the same time, so only one of them is necessary. It is fine to close then reopen the same cursor.
3. Whether you use 2 cursors or reuse just 1 there there is no guarantee the same rows are returned.
4. Your update will not do what you indicated you want. It will update the sal column of every row in the table the number of the loop is performed (in this case the number in AA). So if AA were 3 as for your example each row will have sal updated by 1500. This is because there is no where clause on the update. Therefore Oracle updates every row.